# System of equations involving rank-1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then I want to find all matrices $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that:
\begin{align}
X^T u u^T X &= u u^T \\
X^T v v^T X &= v v^T
\end{align}
[The answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867435/linear-algebra-question-with-rank-1-matrices) analyzes the first equation thoroughly, and finds that the most general solution is
$$
X =
\pmatrix{
P & 0 \\
R & S
}
$$
where $P \in O(1,\mathbb{R})$, $R\in\text{Mat}_{(n-1)\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $S\in\text{Mat}_{(n-1)\times (n-1)}(\mathbb{R})$. Applying this solution to the second equation gives
\begin{align}
X^T v v^T X &=
\pmatrix{
P^T & R^T \\
0 & S^T
} v v^T
\pmatrix{
P & 0 \\
R & S
}
&=
\pmatrix{
(P^T v_1 + R^T v_2)(v_1^T P + v_2^T R) & (P^T v_1 + R^T v_2)v_2^T S \\
S^T v_2 (v_1^T P + v_2^T R) & S^T v_2 v_2^T S
}
\end{align}
where I've set $v = \pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2}$. Equating this matrix to $v v^T$ gives the following conditions:
\begin{align}
0 &= R^T v_2 v_1^T P + P^T v_1 v_2^T R + R^T v_2 v_2^T R \\
v_1 v_2^T &= P^T v_1 v_2^T S + R^T v_2 v_2^T S \\
v_2 v_2^T &= S^T v_2 v_2^T S
\end{align}
I don't see how to find the most general forms of $P,R,S$ which satisfy these equations. Ultimately I would like to generalize this to the case of $m$ equations $X^T u_i u_i^T X = u_i u_i^T$, $1 \le i \le m$, but right now I'm trying to solve the simpler $m = 2$ case. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $X^Tuu^TX=uu^T$ implies that $X^Tu=\pm u$. So, if $U$ denotes the augmented matrix $[u_1,\ldots,u_m]$, then the system of equations
$$
X^Tu_iu_i^TX=u_iu_i^T\ (i=1,2,\ldots,m)\tag{1}
$$
is equivalent to the matrix equation
$$
X^TU=UD\tag{2}
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $\pm1$ and $X,D$ are the unknowns.

Since $(X,D)$ is a solution to $(2)$ iff $(-X,-D)$ is a solution, we may assume that the first diagonal entry of $D$ is $1$. Therefore there are $2^{m-1}$ choices of $D$. For every fixed $D$, the least-norm matrix $X$ that minimises $\|X^TU-UD\|_F$ is $X^T=UDU^+$. It follows that $X^TU=UD$ is solvable if and only if $UD(I_m-U^+U)=0$. And if it is solvable (such as when $D=\pm I$), the general solution $X$ with this $D$ is given by $X^T=UDU^++M(I_n-UU^+)$, where $M$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I understand how $X^T U = UD$ implies $UD(I_m - U^+ U) = 0$, since you can just multiply each side by $I_m - U^+ U$. But I don't follow how you get to the stated solution. First, why does the $X$ which minimizes the Frobenious norm of that equation help us? Second, where does the $M(I_n - U U^+)$ term come from?

Comment: @vibe The equation $X^TU=UD$ is solvable **iff** it is satisfied at the global minimiser of $\|X^TU-UD\|_F$. That's why we are interested in the minimisation problem. As for the term $M(I-UU^+)$, it's just the usual "general solution = particular solution + null space" bit. If $UD(I-U^+U)$ is indeed zero, then $X_0^T=UDU^+$ is a particular solution to the original equation $X^TU=UD$. Since the general solution to the homogeneous linear equation $X^TU=0$ is given by $X_1^T=M(I-UU^+)$, the general solution to the original equation is given by $X^T=X_0^T+X_1^T$.